# Why does this ClientScript throw an undefined error

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a control with an input field and when users hit enter I want the postback to redirect to the page that control was on and scroll to where that input field is on the page. Here's a function that works just fine when I don't programmatically name the function. It generates a function that is unique to the control that uses it and adds that function to the control's `onkeypress`.

## code

```
protected void KeepInView(HtmlInputControl anchor)
{

    string anchorName = anchor.ClientID;
    string defaultEnterScript = @"
                    function handle_{0}(e) {{
                        if (e.key === 'Enter')
                        {{
                            __doPostBack('{1}', '');
                        }}
                    }};";

    string scrollTo = @"
                        $(function(){{
                               console.log('scrolling');
                                var top = document.getElementById('ELEMENT').offsetTop;
                                window.scrollTo(0, top);
                         }});";

    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "defaultEnter", String.Format(defaultEnterScript,anchorName, anchorName), true);
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "scrollTo", String.Format(scrollTo), true);

    anchor.Attributes["onkeypress"] = String.Format("handle_{0}(event);", anchorName);
}
```

## problem

When I hit enter I get the error `handle_uniqueIdentifierName` is not defined. When I change the function name from `handle_{0}()` to a hardcoded name `handle()`; the function is defined and works just fine, but then all controls have the same function and this is not what I want. How do I get my function to be defined when user hits enter.

Comment: Why would you not want them all to use the same function?  It's not like the script is dynamic, you will be running the same exact function with a different name each time.

Comment: @Seano666 I need each control to have different `__doPostBack` params. If I use the same function then the function will have one hardcoded value.

Comment: Can you pass the _doPostBack params as a second argument to a generic function.  Example "handle(event, id);  _doPostBack(id, ''); "